# Cannot get image to follow text in same div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a line of text followed by an image on the same line of a grid with 12 columns.

For some reason image 2 is displaying in line with image 1 text and then image 2 is showing with image 1 text.

It looks like the text and image elements within the div are above/below each other. What I want is them to be side by side.

How do I resolve this? I've posed the code here

http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/P7nzy/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/P7nzy/

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid_6">
    <p class="text">"The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our next order!"</p>
    <p class="image omega"><img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="Contact us"></p>
</div>

<div class="grid_5">
    <p class="image"><img src="img/cheese2.jpg" alt="Contact us"></p>
    <p class="text omega" id="text_left">"Wow, amazing cheese selection and  very fast delivery!"</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    text-align: right;
}

#text_left {text-align: left; }

.image {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border:solid 4px #6b5221;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a width to your text content like shown below.

```
.text {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: right;
    width: 80%; /* added this */
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/P7nzy/4/)

You can use it the way Ollie has mentioned in his answer also. It depends on how you want the appearance to be.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it works in fiddle but on my local machine it still shows text1 and image2 on the same line, I've added all the code to jsfiddle.net/Dano007/P7nzy/5 if that helps?

Comment: @Dano007: I tried adding width to the full code you have posted also and it works. With the details I have so far it is difficult to find out why it doesn't work in your local machine :(

Comment: @OllieCole: Sorry mate, didn't get you. Are you saying that adding width will not work in iOS devices? any reason?

Comment: If you shrink the size of the screen with your way it mucks up again

Comment: Cheers guys, will take a look.

Comment: @OllieCole: Got you, but from the example code provided, I can see that it has to be reduced a lot for it to happen. But good point, noted with thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/P7nzy/2/

What you needed to do was set the display of the text elements to inline like this:

```
display: inline;
```

Also add:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it works in fiddle but on my local machine it still shows text1 and image2 on the same line, I've added all the code to http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/P7nzy/5/ if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

CSS:

```
div.newSection {
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.floatLeft {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

img { height: 50px; }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="newSection">
        <div class="floatLeft">
            <img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="Contact us" />
        </div>
        <div class="floatLeft">"The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our next order!"</div>
    </div>
    <div class="newSection">
        <div class="floatLeft">
            <img src="img/cheese2.jpg" alt="Contact us" />
        </div>
        <div class="floatLeft">"Wow, amazing cheese selection and very fast delivery!"</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markwylde/P7nzy/6/